# Is $6.12345678910111213141516171819202122\ldots$ transcendental?

Tags: decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

My son was busily memorizing digits of $\pi$ when he asked if any power of $\pi$ was an integer.  I told him: $\pi$ is transcendental, so no non-zero integer power can be an integer.

After tiring of memorizing $\pi$, he resolved to discover a new irrational whose expansion is easier to memorize.  He invented (probably re-invented) the number $J$:

$$J = 6.12345678910111213141516171819202122\ldots$$

which clearly lets you name as many digits as you like pretty easily.  He asked me if $J$ is transcendental just like $\pi$, and I said it must be but I didn't know for sure. Is there an easy way to determine this?

I can show that $\pi$ is transcendental (using Lindemann-Weierstrass) but it doesn't work for arbitrary numbers like $J$, I don't think.

Comment: See "Champernowne Constant": http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant

Comment: @Fixee: Off-topic, but by "π is transcendental, so no non-zero power can be an integer" do you mean integer powers, real powers, or powers in general?

Comment: @InterestedQuest: edited to say "integer powers".  My son asked, "can $\pi^2$ or $\pi^3$ or any other power be an integer"?  He meant positive integer powers, and that's what I had intended.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did your son choose an integral part of 6?

Comment: @Adrian: 6 was his age, and $J$ because it's the first letter of his name.

Comment: I see; you've got a bright six-year-old on your hands, there :)

Comment: When he was 3, he asked if 5 was even.  I told him, "No, even means you can cut it in half."  Long pause.... "But 5 is 2 1/2 plus 2 1/2."  He's been like this ever since he could talk. His mother worries about his dating prospects, however.

Comment: your som reminds me when i made a rule of congruence to avoid retaining multiplication table by heart, i think i was 7 yo or something

Comment: @Fixee I realise it's been a while, but what's your son up to these days? Had to ask, sorry.

Comment: He's 14 now and in High School here in the U.S.  Although still very good at math, he now has decided he wants to be a lawyer. :(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a transcendental number, in fact one of the best known ones, it is $6+$ [Champernowne's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).

Kurt Mahler was first to show that the number is transcendental, a proof can be found on his "Lectures on Diophantine approximations", available through [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197407). The argument (as typical in this area) consists in analyzing the rate at which rational numbers can approximate the constant (see the section on "Approximation by rational numbers: Liouville to Roth" in the Wikipedia entry for [Transcendence theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_theory)).

An excellent book to learn about proofs of transcendence is "Making transcendence transparent: an intuitive approach to classical transcendental number theory", by Edward Burger and Robert Tubbs.

Comment: Let me throw in here Ivan Niven's wonderful little book *Irrational Numbers*. It is quite readable by anyone with a mathematical interest. I think it's a Carus Monograph.

Answer (score 23):

This is just the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) plus $6$. Since the Champernowne constant is transcendental, so is this number (as $6$ is, of course, algebraic).

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea it had a name (and I did try Googling, without success).  Is there a straightforward way to confirm its transcendence?

Comment: @Fixee: Don't know, but it was proven transcendental back in 1937.

Comment: Curious question:   Does the fact that this is normal base 10 imply it is transcendental?  Or can we have normal algebraic numbers?

Comment: @Eric Naslund: No, normality is not known to imply transcendence. According to Wikipedia, it is a conjecture that irrational algebraic numbers are normal, though no irrational algebraic number has ever been proven normal.

Comment: Hmm... You just uncovered a typo in Wikipedia! (Somewhere they correctly date the result to 1937; elsewhere, they claim the transcendence was proved in 1961, in Mahler's book I link to in my answer.)