# Is $ 0.112123123412345123456\dots $ algebraic or transcendental?

Tags: decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

Let $$x=0.112123123412345123456\dots $$
Since the decimal expansion of $x$ is non-terminating and non-repeating, clearly $x$ is an irrational number.

Can it be shown whether $x$ is algebraic or transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ ? I think $x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$. But I don't know how to formally prove it. Could anyone give me some help ? Any hints/ideas are much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any replies.

> **My Number:**
>
> $$x=0.\underbrace{1}_{1^{st}\text{ block}}\overbrace{12}^{2^{nd}\text{ block}}\underbrace{123}_{3^{rd}\text{ block}}\overbrace{1234}^{4^{th}\text{ block}}\dots \underbrace{12\dots n}_{n^{th}\text{ block}}\dots $$
> where $n^{th}$ block is the **first $n$ positive integers** for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

(That is the 10th block of $x $ is $12345678910$; The 11th block is $1234567891011$; ... )

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25205/is-this-number-transcendental?rq=1) is related and has some references which might be useful.

Comment: On which field?

Comment: @Panja.S. algebraic refers to being the root of some polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks. I'll try with that question.

Comment: Unclear question! How about the pattern after 123456789?

Comment: It would be followed by 12345678910.

Comment: @HarryPeter my number is 0.11212312341234512345612345671234567812345678912345678910123456789101112345678910111212345678910111213... Is it clear ? :)

Comment: Proving a number to be transcendental rather than algebraic is notoriously difficult. I doubt this one is an easy case.

Comment: The probability that it is algebraic is $\frac{|\mathbb{N}|}{|\mathbb{R}|}=0$.

Comment: It might be better if the number was 0.1121231234123451234561234567123456781234567891234567900123456789011... Make the nth block $\sum_{i=1}^n i 10^{n-i-1}$

Comment: oops. Make the nth block $\sum_{i=1}^n i 10^{n-i}$

Comment: @tomi: The "better form" may change OP's answer, for comparison [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) 0.12345678910111213... is transcendental while $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i/10^i$ = 0.123456790123... = 10/81.

Comment: @barakmanos Actually, probability is measure theory, not cardinality, and probability zero doesn't mean much when dealing with a specific real number.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant#cite_note-5) to a paper proving the Champernowne has irrationality measure $10$ (which proves it is transcendental due to the the [Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem) ). It's probably helpful. I have no access to the paper.

Comment: Your number is in the form of ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty} {{\sum_{m=1}^n m10^{n-m}}\over {10^{\sum_{p=1}^n p}}}$ or if you know a little about triangular numbers $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {{\sum_{m=1}^n m10^{n-m}}\over {10^{T_p}}}$

Comment: @barakmanos but that's true of *every* number.

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, it can be outputed by Turing Machine in real time. Thus under the Hartmanis-Stearns conjecture, it is a transcendental number.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-117-00/S0002-9947-1965-0170805-7/S0002-9947-1965-0170805-7.pdf

Comment: Which theorem in the paper gives this result? More importantly, for me, what does "in real time" mean?

Comment: @CarlMummert   https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/why-the-hartmanis-stearns-conjecture-is-still-open/

Comment: You are misstating the conjecture, the number could be rational (think about $0.0000000...$).

Comment: @MoisheCohen Hmmmm, but is this number periodical? I have not misstated anything

Answer (score 5):

I believe your number can be written as

$$\sum _{j=1}^\infty 10^{-\sum _{m=1}^{j+\frac{1}{2}} \sum _{n=1}^m \left\lceil \log _{10}(n+1)\right\rceil } \left\lfloor c 10^{\sum _{n=0}^j \left\lceil \log _{10}(n+1)\right\rceil }\right\rfloor$$

where $c$ is the Champernowne constant.

Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your number can be written with the following formula:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sum_{r=1}^n r(10)^{n-r}}{10^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$
I don't know how to prove it is transcendental, but I hope this helps!

Comment: I just realized this isn't correct, I didn't account for blocks with two or three decimal digits like 1234567891011...

Comment: If I may ask : What is the procedure that you made to arrive to that expression ?